# performance difference of boost::mutex and boost::timed_mutex

Tags: c++, performance, boost, locking, mutex

I need to protect a resource by mutex. In order to improve diagnosis, I am thinking about deadlock warning using `timed_mutex` (code not tested):

```
boost::timed_mutex m;
// first thread accessing the resource very frequently
while(...){
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock(m);
    // ...
}

// ...
// another thread accessing the resource, only occasionally
while(m.timed_lock(boost::get_system_time()+boost::posix_time::seconds(10)){
   cerr<<"Waiting for lock for (additional) 10 seconds; deadlocked?"<<endl;
}
```

Am I going to see a performance difference with `timed_mutex` when compared with two unconditional locks of a simple `mutex` in both loops? (The platform is POSIX, in case that makes a difference)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is on the implementation of your pthread library. I don't think there is a big difference, but the best you can do is to measure it.